# Set up a Datasource for Tabular Models in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssas-tabular, adventureworks

I want to go through [this tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Implementing-Tabular-Model-Solutions/02). Unfortunately the author has already set up the datasources

[image]

and does not explain how to set them up. First off I installed an separate SSAS Instance in my sql server 2014. Then I tried to add a .mdf file via "Attach" but get the Error "AdventureWorks.detach_log could not be found in the folder". So according to this [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248260/how-to-attach-mdf-with-no-log-file) I tried this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE YAFnet ON (FILENAME = N'C:\sql_data\YAFnet.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

within my SSAS instance query editor but it looks like the query is not a proper one since it is mdx.

Anyone who can help me to get a datasource (adventureworks dw) for my tabular model so I can follow the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would download the tabular backup from [AW samples](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases) and recover the .abf file