# MSSQL DB Browser not coming up

Tags: sql-server, database

I have couple of database on SQL server which were working fine. Now I am no longer able to explore those. What can be the reason?

[image]

Also i am getting below error while trying to turn database on

"File activation failure. The physical file name "D:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSER\DATA\DB_NAME_log.ldf" may be incorrect.
The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This error could occur if the transaction log file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware or environment failure."

Comment: No error message (check your event log)? What is *now* - i.e. since when, and what has changed in the meantime ('nothing' is not an acceptable answer, because stuff constantly changes)? Are you administering all this yourself; if not - did you check with your IT people? What SQL server version are we talking about? *It no longer works* is a question no one can answer.

Comment: Hi @JanDoggen I just spoke to IT people. They have removed .log files of these database. I am not sure if that is causing an issue.

Comment: have the IT people removed the ldf file ? if so than fire them all...There is a method to attach an mdf file without an ldf I just cannot remeber how its called right now

Comment: See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248260/how-to-attach-mdf-with-no-log-file